# Is it possible to change DNS only for a specific program?

Tags: linux-mint, dns, transmission

For some reason, my DNS provider blocks torrent trackers as it appears.

(Proven by connecting to my VPN provider with his DNS which solves the DNS problem.)

But generally speaking, I otherwise like this DoT solution.

I am running Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon with Transmission-GTK 4.0.3.

I would like to change DNS for the torrent app only. Is this possible?

(Heading to bed, and will reply to all comments or answers in the morning.)

Comment: If you run your torrent app in a [container](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/whats-a-linux-container) using something like [Podman](https://podman.io) or [Docker](https://docker.com), you can provide a completely different resolver configuration from the host.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes; but.

Very few programs actually care about DNS. They want *name resolution*. Whether that happens through DNS, some Windows Networking, a lookup in a MySQL database or divine intervention doesn't matter to them – they just call the appropriate libc functions.

Your libc reads some configuration files / asks plugins to do the resolution. By running an application in an environment in which the libc sees a different configuration file, you can make arbitrary changes to the name resolution behaviour, including using a different resolver.

Running your application in a simple container is one solution to achieve that. Check out Jessie Frazelle's https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/ ; she has everything you need already set up, and if you've set up docker correctly, a `make run DIR=transmission-ui`  should do the trick.